# rotate svg fill path box

Tags: html, css, svg

I design box border using `svg` like this :

HTML:

```
<svg class="decor" height="100%" preserveaspectratio="none" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0 L100 100 L0 100" stroke-width="0"></path>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.decor {
  fill: #F00;
  stroke: #e74c3c;
}
```

result:

[image]

Now i need to rotation to this:

[image]

How do generate this?!

DEMO [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k88g5102/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add transform="rotate(180, 50, 50)" to the path

```css
.decor {
  fill: #F00;
  stroke: #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<svg class="decor" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
    <path transform="rotate(180, 50, 50)" d="M0 0 L100 100 L0 100"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
.decor {
  fill: #F00;
  stroke: #e74c3c;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

This will rotate it to be the way you want.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkvp1x8m/